# checked property doesn't work with ngModel

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have the following code inside a form:

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" ngModel [value]="gender" [checked]="gender==='male'" />
    {{gender}}
  </label>
</div>
```

In this situation, neither button is checked by default. If I remove the ngModel, however, then the "male" option is checked by default, as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was both simple and not intuitive. The solution is to modify the radio button like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="selectedGender" [value]="gender" [checked]="gender==='male'" />
```

and then add "selectedGender" as a property in the component.

Comment: You can remove `[checked]="gender==='male'"`.